# What to do if I can't make my app compatible for the Windows Store?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-10, windows-store, desktop-bridge

In my software project I'm heavily using the WinAPI function "SetParent()" to embed multiple instances of a terminal program into my app.

AFAIK there is no way to convert my app into an UWP app, even with the desktop bridge. That's sad because the app is performing very well on Windows 10.

Is there any possibility to still publish it in the Windows Store? Would it be possible to submit something like a stub UWP-app, which would contain only the download link to the .msi package of my non-UWP app which the user could then install?

EDIT:

Using the desktop bridge I could successfully create a .appx package for my .NET 4.6.1 WinForms app. I could also start multiple instances of a Win32 app from my .NET app with Process.Start() and embed its window with SetParent(). The Win32 and the .NET app are running in the same sand box. Both apps have to meet special requirements (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare), otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desktop Bridge apps do not have any API restrictions. You can call any public Windows API, including SetParent. Your app will be allowed in the Store (unless it violates any of the other Store policies of course).

More info on Desktop Bridge: http://aka.ms/desktopbridge

Specifically I recommend reading this topic to prepare for the conversion of your .msi to a Windows App Packge (.appx): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare

Comment: If you run into any problems in the conversion or submission process, please feel free to reach out to me directly (swick at microsoft.com)